# how to curve text in an arc using gimp

Tags: gimp, text, text-on-path

I have a small [tea company](http://pittencrieffteaco.com/) and I'm trying to redesign our logo.

What I would like is for the text to bend in a arc, as if on a coin.

[image]

I would like to render the text as if it's "*backbone*" were shaped in the following way:

[image]

Or even a "softer" (i.e. slightly flatter) arc.

Towards this end I've watched some tutorials online- I point them out below.

[This tutorial](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=10932) is the most useful resource I've found thus far.

Also [this one](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130519000612AAFsj4a), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THLTFDt8uuw).

The general consensus is to use

```
Filters > Distorts > Curve Bend
```

but this makes the text very "fat" in the center and small on the sides.

People also mention

```
Map > Map Object >
```

But there isn't an arc, only a circle or a cylinder and these options also horribly distort the text.

Is there a good way, using Gimp, to render my text in a nice gentle arc- for instance to fit the ellipse I linked to from my site, or even a sharper arc, as if on a coin?

Answer (score 9):

If your text is a text layer (preview replaced by a **`T`** icon), then:

- Make a Path that follows the arc,
- Use *Layer>Text along path* (this menu is only available on text layers).
- This creates another path, which is your text following the arc path.
- *Select>From path* to create a selection from this
- Bucket-fill the selection.

Slightly complex, but the result is much sharper than with other methods There are however two drawbacks:

1. The text is left-justified on the path when you usually want it
   centered
2. Characters are slightly distorted

The [`ofn-text-long-path` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) gives you many more options for formatting/positioning the text and uses a different method to create the characters to avoid distortion.

Comment: Is there really no way to center text on a path in Gimp?  I'm surprised.  (I hoped to find a feature request to link here, but a short search turned up nothing; I may try a more careful search later.)

Comment: Not with out-of-the-box Gimp, but this is a feature (among others) of the mentioned script: [examples from the doc](https://imgur.com/PbbRBAh)